# How to set and parse a Backbone Model that already exists in a Collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm trying to update a Backbone model within a collection using `set`, I also want to `parse` this model so the attributes match up with the other models but I'm having no success. Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong? When I pass `parse:true` as an option when setting the model it doesn't get called?

Is it a case of calling parse directly then setting the model?

**JS**

```
    var data = {
    "request": "12345678",
    "success": true,
    "orders": [{
        "n": "Joe",
        "v": 123,
        "id": 1
    }, {
        "n": "Jane",
        "v": 456,
        "id": 2
    }]
};

var Order = Backbone.Model.extend({

    parse: function(response) {
        console.log('Model parse before', response);

        response.name = response.n;
        response.value = response.v;

        delete response.n;
        delete response.v;

        console.log('Model parse after', response);

        return response;
    }
});

var Orders = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Order,

    initialize: function() {
        this.listenTo(this, 'update', function(model) {
            console.log('Model update', model);
        });

        setTimeout(function() {
            this.updateModel(2);
        }.bind(this), 1000);

        this.listenTo(this, 'change', function(model, options) {
            console.log(model, options);
        });
    },

    updateModel: function(id) {
        console.log('updateModel');

        var modelToUpdate = this.findWhere({
            id: id
        });

        console.log('modelToUpdate', modelToUpdate);

        modelToUpdate.set({
            "n": "Jane",
            "v": 985,
            "id": 2
        }, {
            parse: true
        });
    },

    parse: function(response) {
        console.log('Collection parse', response.orders);
        return response.orders;
    }
});

var orders = new Orders(data, {
    parse: true
});
```

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kyllle/9hfk5g6q/

Answer (score 1):

`parse` method is only called when the model is created inside a collection.

In your case, the model is already part of the collection. So when you set the data on the existing model, the parse is not called since it is not part of the backbone `set` method implementation for the model.

You need to call it explicitly on the model.